# Using useSwaggerUI extension method getting registered only once, when called two times

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swagger-ui

I am facing issue while calling useSwaggerUI extension method twice.
Only the first called end point i.e. c.SwaggerEndpoint("/docs/customer/swagger.json", "Customers Api Doc")  gets registered in this case.

Basically, it is called twice because my web api uses two different Nuget packages(for two types of authorization) and is called once in each nuget package.

```js
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
 c.SwaggerEndpoint("/docs/customer/swagger.json", "Customers Api Doc");
});
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
 c.SwaggerEndpoint("/docs/employee/swagger.json", "Employee Api Doc");
});
```

Please help if anyone faced similar issues before.